# Are there better bounds than those given by Chebyshev and Markov?

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

If we first consider the Markov's inequality, it tells us that if the expected value $E[X]$ is small, then the probability that X takes a very large value is small
$$\mathbb{P}(X\geq a)\leq\dfrac{E[X]}{a}$$
clearly we only have a little information about this random variable $X$
and if we want a better bound for this probability we can use the Chevyshev's inequality
$$P(X\geq a)\leq\dfrac{\sigma²}{(a-E[X])²}$$ but we must have more information than before, that is ($\sigma²$ and $E[X]$).

My question is:

Are there more inequalities that give a better bound for this probability?
In such a case, what information about the random variable is used? When should these best bounds be applied?

Comment: You can look into higher order moments to bound the right tail. For instance, Markov actually works with $\mathbb{E}[X^n]/a^n$ where $n > 0$. There’s also a Chernoff bound that works well with an independent sum of variables. In many cases, when applied correctly, Chernoff can give you exponential decay rather than polynomial given by Markov/Chebyshev.

Comment: Concentration inequalities are a huge topic. The [book by Boucheron, Lugosi, and Massart (large PDF file)](https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%20inequalities.pdf) is one well-recommended reference.